# How can i solve MATLAB percentage getting always zero?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate how much image has higher 'red channel entropy' than 'blue channel entropy'. I wanted the result in percentage. But it is always showing zero. But I have checked the random single image, and some of them satisfy the condition. how can I solve this error?
I am using MATLAB R2015b

```
folder = 'F:\raw-890\';
filePattern = fullfile(folder, '*.png');
myFiles = dir(filePattern); % the folder inwhich ur images exists
for k = 1 : length(myFiles)
   fullFileName = fullfile(folder, myFiles(k).name);
   I= imread(fullFileName);
   Red = I(:,:,1);
   Green = I(:,:,2);
   Blue = I(:,:,3);
   %I = I(:); % Vectorization of RGB values
   p = imhist(Red); % Histogram
   p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
   p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
   Er = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);
   p = imhist(Blue); % Histogram
   p(p == 0) = [ ];% remove zero entries in p
   p = p ./ numel(I); % normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
   Eb = round(-sum(p.*log2(p)),3);
end
percentage = sum(Er > Eb) / numel(Er) * 100; % Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy
disp(['Percentage of images with red entropy higher than blue entropy: ' num2str(percentage)])
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? What's the type of `p`?

Comment: With proper indenting you can immediately tell what the problem is: `Er` and `Eb` are overwritten with a new scalar value in every loop iteration, but you expect these to be arrays at the end of the loop.